# SQL CASE Selection Statement Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, case

Fairly new to SQL programming.

I'm trying to create a stored procedure which will take the users name, compare it to the users table to retrieve their 'role' and then select all pieces of Feedback from the Feedback table which are related to them.

There are currently 3 possible values:
- User
- Governance Board
- Admin

If the Role is either 'Governance Board' or 'Admin' I want all entries in the table to be retrieved
However if the Role is 'User' I only want the entries where the [publish] column is set to true or the 'Author' or 'IdentifiedBy' column is set to themselves.

This is what I currently have however it is throwing errors around the case statement

```
@Alias varchar(max),
AS

DECLARE @Role varchar(max)

SET @Role =
(
    SELECT [Role] FROM [CSLL].[Users] WHERE [Alias] = @Alias
)

CASE
    WHEN @Role = "Admin" THEN SELECT * FROM [CSLL].[Feedback]
    WHEN @Role = "Governance Board" THEN SELECT * FROM [CSLL].[Feedback]
    WHEN @Role = "User" THEN SELECT * FROM [CSLL].[Feedback] WHERE [Publish] = True OR [Author] = @Alias or [IdentifiedBy]=@Alias
    ELSE
END
```

Any help would be most appreciated. I'm sure it's just something that I'm doing which is dumb but being new to SQL I can't spot it.

Thanks in advance

Tom

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** that can return one of various values - it is **NOT** a flow control statement like in other languages, it cannot be used to run one piece of code or another. For that, you need to use `IF` and `ELSE` exclusively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this query as a single `select`.

```
select f.*
from Feedback f cross join
     (SELECT [Role] FROM [CSLL].[Users] WHERE [Alias] = @Alias) r
where (r.[role] in ('Admin', 'Governance Board') ) or
      (r.[role] = 'User' and ([Publish] = True OR [Author] = @Alias or [IdentifiedBy] = @Alias))
```

I think keeping the logic in one place and having a single query is better from the perspective of undersatnding the logic and maintaining the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use CASE this way to control flow.  You have to use IF.

```
IF @Role='Admin'
  SELECT * FROM [CSLL].[Feedback]
ELSE IF @Role='Governance Board'
  SELECT * FROM [CSLL].[Feedback]
ELSE IF ... etc
```

Comment: That and the problem with double-quotes

Comment: Yeah I went ahead and fixed that, but I guess I should have mentioned it as well, thanks.

Comment: Yes, mentioning it so the OP knows there's a difference might be useful

Comment: Thanks a lot - is working now. Had read somewhere you couldn't really use IF statements in SQL guess will ignore that.

Comment: IF statements have the opposite restriction:  you can't use them in a SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

Case statements have to be inside of a select.  You can use if instead.

```
if(@Role = "Admin")
then
    select * from CSLL.Feedback;
else if(...)
```

Or you can put the case in the where clause:

```
select *
from CSLL.Feedback
where
CASE
WHEN @Role = "Admin" THEN [IdentifiedBy]
WHEN @Role = "Governance Board" THEN [IdentifiedBy]
WHEN @Role = "User" THEN @Alias
END
IN (IdentifiedBy, Author)
OR [Publish] = True
```